# Is CKN in MACsec considered as secret value?

Tags: network

I know Connectivity that the Connectivity Association key(CAK) should be kept secret. What about the Connectivity Association name(CKN)? Is it considered a secret?

Comment: For those of us who have no idea what CAK or CKN are, can you provide some links? Is "Connectivity" or "MACsec" the name of the software you're using?

Comment: MACsec is layer 2 security protocol defined in IEEE 802.1AE. The terminology comes from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the CKN is not considered secret; it's public information. It's openly (unencrypted) transported as part of the MACsec Key Agreement (MKA) packets as identification for the secure Connection Association (CA). See IEEE 802.1X for more details.